# memory leakage when pushing struct and poping from std::queue

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a struct that I push it to `std::queue` from one thread and than pop from another.operations are thread safe but there is leak in leak detector.

```
struct Data
{
  double  x,y;
  float   z;
  float  a,b,c;     
  int frame;
  double timestamp;
  Data& operator=(const SDTNavData& rhs);

};

Data& Data::operator=(const Data& rhs)
{
  if (this != &rhs)
   {
     x= rhs.lat;
     y= rhs.lon;
     z= rhs.alt;

     a= rhs.yaw;
     b = rhs.pitch;
     c  = rhs.roll;

     frame = rhs.frame;

    timestamp = rhs.timestamp;
}

return *this;
}
```

When I create a `std::queue` and push and pop data from queue it gives me leakage report

```
Data d;
std::queue<Data> my_queue;

my_queue.push(d);

D new=my_queue.front();

my_queue.pop();
```

Comment: Is your memory profiler capable of handling multiple threads? If not then maybe is a false report.

Comment: but i see that the memory usage is increasing in task manager on windows

Comment: What the statement `D new=my_queue.front();` does?

Comment: assigns created variable to front of the queue

Comment: I think is not syntactically correct. Also, unless I'm missing something the input argument in the definition of overloaded `operator=` does not correspond to the input argument in its declaration.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use `new` as a variable name. `new` is a keyword and that should not compile. Post your real code.

Comment: This actually compiles? Where are the multiple threads you where talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Making an educated guess because the code you posted has several issues. I assume that the problem that you have is that you are pushing in your queue `Data d` before you allocate it in memory:

```
Data *d;
std::queue<Data*> my_queue;
my_queue.push(d);
d = new Data();   
my_queue.pop();
```

The above is wrong because in the queue you're pushing a copy of `d` not `d`. Instead the following is correct:

```
Data *d;
d = new Data();
std::queue<Data*> my_queue;
my_queue.push(d);
...
my_queue.pop();
```

Now the copy of `d` that is pushed in the queue points to the allocated memory.

Comment: `d = new Data();` won't compile. The `new` expression returns a pointer and you are trying to assign it to an object.

Comment: My suggestion would be to completely avoid `new` and pointers in the code. There doesn't appear to be a compelling reason to do manual memory management here and the easiest way to fix leaks is to stop using `new`.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I totally agree, but this is an assumption after all.